# object reference not set exception while getting datarow in asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, datarow

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object` exception occur while getting `DataRow` from `DataTable`. Can anyone give solution for this.

The code i am trying is shown below:

```
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from input_alignments", cn);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
DataTable table = ds.Tables["input_alignments"];
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)//here exception occur
{
sb.Append(row["word1"].ToString();
}
```

What could be the reason for the exception?

Comment: Can you show us declaration for `sb`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your query returns only one resultset, you can simply have your data loaded like this:

```
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from input_alignments", cn);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
DataTable table = ds.Tables[0];         // use integer index instead of string one
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    sb.Append(row["word1"].ToString();
}
```

Also, make sure that `sb` is properly initialized.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you forgot to add the table "input_alignments" to the dataset before filling it.

The documentation gives an example of this here:

```
DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
dataset.Tables.Add("aaa");
adapter.Fill(dataset, "AAA"); // Fills table "aaa" because only one similarly named table is in the DataSet.
```

What is likely to happen is that the table, since not being declared, will not be a Reference in your foreach loop. You could try to verify this by using a reference to .Tables[0] instead of the name, which is missing.

Entire documentation on DataSet.Fill() here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4b211hz(v=vs.110).aspx